# Gzipping a js files creates an archive instead of attaching gz extension on the file output

Tags: javascript, gzip

When I gzip a javascript file, the output becomes a gz type archive folder, while inside the archive folder there is the original js file. My requirement is not to create an archive but to create a gzip version of a the javascript file without the archive folder. I would like to gzip js files and let the browser decode it.

Have tried these commands:

1) gzip -c filename.js > filename.js.gz

2) gzip filename.js

Either ways it creates an archive.

Comment: `gz` files are not "a folder". A `gz` file can only contain a single file, encoded. There is no other way to do what you are doing. If you are getting a folder at decompression time, it is the fault of your decompression software doing the wrong thing.

Comment: I am not decompressing or unzipping, Its about gzipping a single js file, while doing that thru command line it creates an archive folder with a gz extension, instead of the file with the gz extension

Comment: Again: `gz` file is *not a folder*. Your OS or unarchive utility can *present* it to you as a folder, but it is just a file. More specifically, even true multi-file archives like `zip` are just one file, but can be presented as a folder. They are not a folder, despite looking like one, unless you actually *extract* them into a folder.

Comment: Even though it might have a folder-like icon, a gzip file is an archive, always. I think you believe that gzip (just assuming here) is some sort of minifier or something but all it does is create an archive with the archived file(s) inside. Some servers use output compression to send their responses as gzip to browsers to save bandwidth but all they do is make a gzip archive which the client will then decompress.

Comment: Thank You @Amadan for the useful information

Comment: Understood the exact difference between gzipping and minification, Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found the answer which is what works most of the times. I enabled gzip compression in my tomcat configuration as follows and from my side I only had to minify/obfuscate the files and gzipping encoding/decoding would be done by server and client.

In Tomcat7/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"/>
```

Also for complete documentation on all parameters used here, refer to [tomcat7-config-docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)